# How to make WCF Facility instantiate service eagerly rather than lazy? (WindsorCastle)

Tags: c#, wcf, castle-windsor, ioc-container, windsor-facilities

I have registered a WCF service with WindsorContainer like this:

```cs
        var container = new WindsorContainer();
        container.AddFacility<WcfFacility>(f => f.CloseTimeout = TimeSpan.Zero);
        container.Register(
            Component.For<ITestService>()
                .ImplementedBy<TestService>()
                .Named("TestService")
                .AsWcfService());
```

The `TestService` object is instantiated when first WCF request is created. 
What I'd like instead is to manually instantiate it at time when I want to, like this:

```cs
container.Resolve<ITestService>();
```

(eg. when user clicks the "Turn ON" button from the GUI).

Clients should simply get error when connecting, until service is started.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Please tell us what you've tried.

Comment: Well there aren't many things I could try from what I know. I tried passing argument to .AsWcfService() like this .AsWcfService(new DefaultServiceModel().OpenEagerly()) but that had the same effect as before. I am using named pipes as transport mechanism. The fact is that as soon as .AsWcfService() is executed I can see that named pipe is created on the system (I use sysinternals tool to see that) even though TestService object is not instantiated. Only when first call to WCF service is made I see that TestService constructor is called. This is unwanted behavior for me, so can I change it?

Comment: Presumably this is self hosted - otherwise there is no GUI in which to "turn on" the service. So simply don't start listening (call Open) until you're ready to receive requests.